# create a page for each row in table with php

Tags: php, dynamic

I've got a table with 10 apps in it, I want a page for each of those apps which will look the same but have different information on it. I'm new to PHP so don't really know what to search for.. are there any good resources out there that could help me?

I want the url structure to be like:

/apps/title1

/apps/title2

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is query something based on the GET data.  You can then use `.htaccess` or `$_SEREVR['REQUEST_URI']` to fetch the link.

So if they went to site.com/?app=Stack you could use this.

```
echo $_GET['app'];
```

Which would output Stack.

Comment: I don't want the urls to look like that though, and i was going to develop this further so the url could be `/category/title1` etc.

Comment: I said it in my post. "You can then use .htaccess or $_SEREVR['REQUEST_URI'] to fetch the link.".